# Extended core class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have some codeigniter application. It works well on my local server. After I uploaded it to the hosting server it won't work and resulting an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'System_Controller' not found in /home/k2113138/public_html/test/application/controllers/login.php on line 3
```

Here is my System Controller that extending CI_Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

//location: application/core/    
class System_Controller extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            //some code
        }
    }
```

my controller:

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  //location: application/controllers/
  class Login extends System_Controller {

public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
  }
```

i have set my config as my desired configuration like this:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['base_url'] = 'http://xx.com/subfolder/';
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'System_';
?>
```

I have read many article that discuss this matter but still cannot found the solution. Really confuse about the problem, because everything works well in local server. I have configured the config file as what it's needed like the database and the routes configuration. Is there any other things that i need to re-configure?

EDIT: My Codeigniter version is 2.1.3

Comment: Where did you put the file with the `System_Controller`?

Comment: i have wrote it above. In application/core. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, i see, i'm think that it could be a *filename* capitalization issue, it should be `System_Controller.php` (uppercase S and C) to make CI pick it up.

Comment: Hey, i have done what you're suggest to me. Renamed my system_controller.php, but still won't work. Any other idea? sorry before.

Comment: I'm puzzled, try printing the path [CI checks here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/CodeIgniter.php#L237) to see where the file should be according to CI. Just add a `die(APPPATH.'core/'.$CFG->config['subclass_prefix'].'Controller.php')` before the `if`, try `var_dump()`-ing the `file_exists()`.

Comment: you know what? this is what it printed:
application/core/System_Controller.php

Comment: And what happens if you do `file_exists()` on that path?

Comment: try to check the file permission on your server for this file and compare it with others.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you changed the `filename` to lowercase, now, try change the `classname` too:

```
class system_controller extends CI_Controller
```

If don't run, play with the classname and the filename, this is a problem of your server, very common in shared servers.

Sometimes, the PHP version and its configuration, play a important rol in this cases.